# Call a second php script from within a first php script

Tags: php, http-headers, shopify

I have a script that receives a webhook from Shopify and adds subscribers to a database, if certain products are purchased. The script works, but it takes too long to process. The Shopify webhook only listens for a response for 5 seconds before repeating. My script takes an average of 5.5-7 seconds. The result is that my script is firing multiple times because Shopify isn't getting the http 200 in time.

I've tried using ob_start(); ob_flush(); to force the header(); to send at the beginning of the script, but it's not working. So, I want to split this process into two scripts: the first receives the webhook, checks for the required products, and if the products are found, sets a session variable and calls another php file. Then the first script will end so the http response will be sent. Meanwhile, the second script will access the session variable to processes the subscriber database functions, without any concern for how long it takes.

How do I tell a second php file to activate from my first script? Or, if simpler, how can I force the http 200 to send immediately?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please post the code you are using so far in order to make this a good question.

Comment: The code is pretty long. I'm gonna check into the queue suggestion below. If better etiquette is to post the code anyway, I will.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider using a queue.

1. Shopify sends the webhook to your website
2. your webhook.php script receives the notification, and saves the parameters in a queue, and sends the 200 code back. Should be done in milliseconds
3. a background task consumes the queue and does the heavy lifting (adding subscribers in your database)

You can either:

- use a SaaS queue systems like Amazon's SQS or Rackspace's Queue
- install a queueing system on your server like RabbitMQ
- develop your own queueing system, as simple or as complex as you wish it to be. Could even be a simple file or database table containing the info to process

Comment: Yep, queues are the answer here.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check into this.